# Automating the data for running Time Manager plugin

Tags: qgis, timemanager

I am trying to create some animated maps using the Time Manager plugin, however, not all the rows in my CSV file populate values for my fields of interest.

Basically, I want to be able to automatically remove the rows in my attribute table which do not have the required timestamp populated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set up a filter on the layer so that QGIS will ignore any feature with a null value in the date field.

> Layer Properties > General > Query Builder (under Provider feature filter)

Substitute the name of your time stamp field in this expression:

> "timestamp" is not null

Now QGIS will completely ignore any features without a time stamp. They won't show up in the attribute table or on the map.